# Command window not closing when running a scrapy spider via a batch file

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file, cmd, scrapy, windows-7-x64

I wrote a scrapy spider and it's working great when I run it from a command window. So now I want to automate it to run with a batch file (I'm running windows 7).

I wrote this batch file:

```
@echo off
cd c:\scrapy\callStats
scrapy crawl logspider
exit
```

This does run the spider, but after the spider is done, the cursor just blinks and the window doesn't close.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Is `scrapy` a `scrapy.bat` Batch file? If so, then you must add a `call` command before it: `call scrapy crawl logspider`

Comment: No - It's referring to the scrapy.exe file in my python scripts folder.

Comment: Then the `scrapy.exe` program is the one that not ends... You may test this by open a second cmd.exe session, enter `tasklist` and see if `scrapy.exe` is active.

Comment: I ran tasklist during the crawl and after the spider said that it was closed. Scrapy.exe was on the tasklist during the crawl, but wasn't there after the spider said it was closed.